# How to consecutively search for existing documents and modify/add each one accordingly?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

As a javascript newbie I have some troubles with consecutively checking and updating multiple documents in mongodb database.

To briefly describe the main function, it receives a name of item along with a string of multiple tags, which is transformed into array. Then, for each tag (element of array), I would like to check if the document with such name already exists in the collection. If it doesn't, the tag should just be added to the collection. If it does, the id of the user who added the tag should be added to the document.

The described function is the following:

```
router.post('/saveBand', isAuthenticated, function(req, res){
console.log(req.session.passport.user);
var userId = req.session.passport.user;
var bandName = req.body.title;
var description = req.body.description;
var tags = req.body.tags;
var tagsArray = tags.split(',');
var tagIds = [];

var done = 0;
for (var i=0; i <= tagsArray.length; i++){
    var tagName = tagsArray[i];
    console.log("Saving tag " + tagName);
    Tag.findOne({title: tagName}, function(err, tag){
        if(!err){
            console.log("Saving tag after search: " + tagName);
            if(!tag){
                tag = new Tag();
                tag.title = tagName;
                tag.users = [userId];
                console.log("Saving tag " + tag);
                tagIds.push(tag._id);
                tag.save(function(err){
                    if(!err) {
                        console.log("successfully saved " + tagName);
                    }
                    else {
                        console.log("Error: could not save tag " + tagName);
                    }
                    done++;
                    if(done== tagsArray.length){
                        saveBand();
                    }
                });
            }else{
                if(tag.users.indexOf(userId) < 0){
                    tag.users.push(userId);
                    tag.save(function(err){
                        if(!err) {
                            console.log("successfully saved " + tagName);
                        }
                        else {
                            console.log("Error: could not save tag " + tagName);
                        }
                        done++;
                        if(done== tagsArray.length){
                            saveBand();
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
        }
    });
}
saveBand = function(){
    console.log("all tags saved. Saving band...");
    console.log(bandName);
    var band = new Band({
        title: bandName,
        note: description,
        _owner: userId,
        tags: tagIds
    });
    band.save(function(err){
        if(err){
            console.log(err);
        }
        else{
            console.log("Successfully added band");
        }
        res.redirect("/timeline");
    });
}
```

The output log for example execition is the following:
559f9e9d32a642d27e001730

```
Saving tag band1
Saving tag band2
Saving tag band3
Saving tag undefined
Saving tag after search: undefined
Saving tag { title: undefined,
  _id: 55a12109adbe22a254ab34cc,
  users: [ 559f9e9d32a642d27e001730 ] }
Error: could not save tag undefined
Saving tag after search: undefined
Saving tag { title: undefined,
  _id: 55a12109adbe22a254ab34cd,
  users: [ 559f9e9d32a642d27e001730 ] }
Error: could not save tag undefined
Saving tag after search: undefined
Saving tag { title: undefined,
  _id: 55a12109adbe22a254ab34ce,
  users: [ 559f9e9d32a642d27e001730 ] }
Error: could not save tag undefined
all tags saved. Saving band...
my test band
Saving tag after search: undefined
Saving tag { title: undefined,
  _id: 55a12109adbe22a254ab34d0,
  users: [ 559f9e9d32a642d27e001730 ] }
Error: could not save tag undefined
Successfully added band
```

From the above log I guess the tagName is not passed to the function Tag.FindOne(). Besides, I guess the implementation of the desired (described) logic is not good.

I would be very thankful if anyone could help to modify the above function in order to check for each tag if it already exists and add/modify it accordingly.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One issue is that the for loop is going from index 0 to index tagsArray.length which is 4. The array only has 4 entries so when it reaches tagsArray[4] it returns undefined.

Another is that the callback from findOne will run after the for loop has finished iterating and tagName is at its final value which is undefined. This is why you see "Saving tag undefined" for everything.

You can fix both of these issues by changing your for loop into a forEach e.g.

```
tagsArray.forEach(function(tagName){ ... })
```